# bxslider displaySlideQty issue

Tags: jquery, bxslider

i am currently building a slider with bxslider. i thought it was all working fine until i needed to add an active class to the current slide. I got this working fine, but in my source code i noticed that the slides were getting duplicated twice if not 3 times. I only have 3 slides in my slider. i have set displaySlideQty to 3 and moveSlideQty to 1.

the problem is the active class is getting added but then not removed from the duplicates slides. below is my jquery code for bxslider:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var slider = $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    controls: false,
    displaySlideQty: 3,
    moveSlideQty: 1,

    onBeforeSlide: function(currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject){
        $('.pager').removeClass('active-slide');   
         $(currentSlideHtmlObject).next().addClass('active-slide');
 //     $('#sddf').html('<p class="check">Slide index ' + currentSlide + ' of ' + totalSlides + ' total slides has completed.');

    }
```

here is my html:

```
<ul id="slider1" style="overflow:hidden; margin:auto;">
     <li id="slidel" style="width:960px;">
      <?php include('includes/sliders/center.php'); ?>
    </li>

    <li id="slidec" style="width:960px;">
      <?php include('includes/sliders/left.php'); ?>
    </li>
    <li id="slider" style="width:960px;">
      <?php include('includes/sliders/right.php'); ?>
    </div>
  </ul>
```

and here is the output in firebug:

```
<ul id="slider1" style="overflow: hidden; margin: auto; width: 999999px; position: relative; left: -960px;">
<li id="slider" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
<li id="slidel" class="pager" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
<li id="slidec" class="pager active-slide" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
<li id="slider" class="pager" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
<li id="slidel" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;" class="active-slide">
<li id="slidec" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
<li id="slider" style="width: 960px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;">
</ul>
```

notice above that there are 2 active classes. the bottom one will not change.

iv spent almost a day on this and not got anywhere! any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers, Dan